# python - class - AttributeErr - but method defined

Tags: python

```
class Card(object):
    suitList = ("Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades")
    rankList = ("narf", "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King")

    def __init__(self, suit = 0, rank = 2):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank
    def __str__ (self):
        return "%s of %s" % (self.rankList[self.rank], self.suitList[self.suit])
    # override built-in compare function:
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        # use if instead of if...elif..else
        if self.suit > other.suit: return 1
        if self.suit < other.suit: return -1

        if self.rank == 1 and other.rank != 1: return 1
        if self.rank != 1 and other.rank == 1: return -1
        if self.rank > other.rank: return 1
        if self.rank < otehr.rank: return -1

        return 0

# test code
card1 = Card(0, 12)
card2 = Card(1, 2)
print card1.cmp(card2)
```

below is the err msg:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\OOP_thecardclass.py", line 29, in 
    print card1.cmp(card2)
AttributeError: 'Card' object has no attribute 'cmp'

Why?

Comment: `__cmp__` is deprecated, use the individual rich comparison methods, with `functools.total_ordering` if you want. Also, don't call it directly, use comparison operators as usual.

Answer (score 2):

That must be `__cmp__`, not `cmp`:

```
print card1.__cmp__(card2)
```

Answer (score 1):

`__cmp__` != `cmp`. Try using `==` or `!=` instead, as the reason for implementing `__cmp__` is for these operators. You don't use `__cmp__` directly, you use it to "overload" operators. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad-hoc_polymorphism